# Abort cURL in a ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, curl

I'm sending an Ajax request to `ajax.php` file that downloads an XML using cURL.

```
//ajax.php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,       USERNAME.':'.PASSWORD);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    getData());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,       $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,    1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,    5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,     true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

echo $data;
```

User is not confirmed about this process and may refresh the webpage.

Sometimes `curl_exec($ch)` takes a long time and i get a `timeout` error. this error prevent script to continue. I searched and found no exact solution to solve this problem.

Now the the bigger problem is that in this case while ajax request is processing in background and user refresh the page, it wont refresh until ajax request timeout or ended.

I thought aborting that cURL request when page refreshed is a good temporarily solution but don't know how to do that.

**Note:** Ajax request has been setup using jQuery and aborting it `ajax.abort()` did not solved the problem.

Comment: You know that you can answer your own question, right?

Comment: @wormhit Done friend! but how it could help me ?

Comment: A lot of users are not answering question as soon as they see that answer rate is low. You're loosing users that will actually look into your question. I'm not judging you or anything. Just info.

Comment: @wormhit [You're mistaken](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110644/148672)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the way how your application is handling this functionality.
I would try to put another abstraction layer between ajax call and actual calculation process.

For example, ajax call could initialize php background process or even better middleware message queue with workers. In response you give to customer job id (or store it in db linked together with user id). Then onTimeout() is executing ajax requests to get status of job. In the mean time background process or middleware worker is processing the task and saves response into db with the same job id.

So in the end customer initializes job and after that just checks status of that job. When job is finished, you know it on server side. So on next ajax request you respond with actual job result. Javascript is receiving response with result and is executing callback function that is continuing work on client side.

Comment: I think you didn't understand what the problem is. may be my question is not cleared. I'm not worry about ajax request result or any session, what will cause my program to have problem is the webpage that calls ajax, It wont refresh while ajax request is proccessing.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using a try/catch block to return something that you could deal with whenever this (or other) error occur.

Comment: I still should wait for cURL request and try/catch is useless